# was/is + past tense

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, past-tense, grammaticality-in-context

Which of these sentences is right?

Why would you review a file that ***was*** closed?

or

Why would you review a file that ***is*** closed?

And, would it make a difference if ***already*** was added: Why would you review a file that ***was/is already*** closed?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. The confusion lies in that "closed" can either be the past tense of the verb "close", or an adjective in its own right. It is a participle, an adjective that is derived from a verb. Specifically it is a past-participle, derived from a past-tense verb. Most past-participles imply that their modified nouns (the file in the above examples) have undergone the action of the participle's originating verb. (Additional examples of past-participles include "marked" and "cut").

I would parse the first sentence, due to the alignment of tenses, as having a past-tense verb, and talking about a file that has already had an action "close" applied to it.

I would parse the second sentence, due to the mis-alignment of tenses, as having a past-participle, and talking about a file that has the status of being "closed" or "not open".

The two sentences are broadly interchangeable; however, depending on the specific context, there might be differences, for example, a situation or environment where a file can be re-opened. The first sentence does not address this possibility directly; the second sentence implies that if this is possible, then it has not happened (or if the file has been re-opened, it was then closed again).

Again, the first sentence only talks about past actions applied to the file; the second talks about the current state of the file.

The addition of "already" doesn't change this, however, it does imply that the result of a review would be to close the file (which would set it into "closed" status).